# Equivalent of spectral density function related to fBm: $\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\vert \lambda+2k\pi\vert^{-2H-1}$

Tags: real-analysis, stochastic-calculus, special-functions

Let $H\in (0,1/2)\cup (1/2,1)$. For $\lambda\in [-\pi,\pi]$ let $$f_H(\lambda)=\vert e^{i\lambda}-1\vert^2 \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\vert \lambda+2k\pi\vert^{-2H-1}.$$

I am reading a book that say "it easy to see that $$f_H(\lambda)\sim  \vert \lambda\vert ^2\vert \lambda\vert ^{-2H-1}=\vert \lambda\vert^{-2H+1}$$
as $\lambda\to 0.$"

It will follow for exemple from $$\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\vert 1+\frac{2k\pi}{\lambda}\vert^{-2H-1}\to 1$$ as $\lambda\to 0.$ But I don't see how to prove this kind of limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for $\lambda\in [-\pi,\pi]$ and $\alpha>1$,
$$
\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}|\lambda+2\pi k|^{-\alpha}=2\sum_{k=1}^\infty(\lambda+2\pi k)^{-\alpha}+|\lambda|^{-\alpha}.
$$
By monotone convergence, it is clear that you can take the limit $\lambda\to 0$ in the first sum. Hence,
$$
|\lambda|^{-2}|\lambda|^{\alpha} |e^{i\lambda}-1|^2\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}|\lambda+2\pi k|^{-\alpha}=\frac{|e^{i\lambda}-1|^2}{|\lambda|^2}\left(2|\lambda|^{\alpha}\sum_{k=1}^\infty(\lambda+2\pi k)^{-\alpha}+1\right)\to 1
$$
as $\lambda\to 0$.

Comment: Ah I was focused on dominated convergence theorem but forgot the monote convergence! Thanks

Comment: it also works with DCT.

Comment: Ah right! $\alpha>1$!